# Django-rest-framework: rewrite default form validaiton

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-validation

I have recently started to use django-rest-framework in my projects and I have faced a problem.
Here is a simple auth form I have:

```
<form action="{% url 'rest_framework:login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="e-mail" name="username" value="" placeholder="Логин" maxlength="100" required="required">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Пароль" maxlength="100" required="required">
    <button type="submit" class="lightbluebtn">Войти</button>
</form>
```

I can't really figure out how to validate it. I just need the error to be shown on the form.
Every time I submit my form with invalid data I redirected to rest-framework login page.
Also I have django-rest-framework default urls:

```
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

Is there any way to use it with django default forms?

Can you guys help me to fix it?
I will be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if for the api you are using a [session authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) then you don't need the rest_framework login page, that page is useful usually in the dev environment, you can just point to the `{% url 'login' %}` page (that uses django.contrib.auth.views.login view), and override that template by naming yours `registration/login.html` , for outputting form errors just use `{{ form.error }}`, like for example:

```
{# file registration/login.html #}
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <p>Your email and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="e-mail" name="username" value="" placeholder="Логин" maxlength="100" required="required">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Пароль" maxlength="100" required="required">
    <button type="submit" class="lightbluebtn">Войти</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to use: url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.login', name='login') but unfortunately got the error "TypeError login() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Comment: @stk-13 the correct path is 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', the one you are citing is called by that view